# Java cursor giving only 50 rows

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am using this cursor but facing problem in it

it is returning only 50 rows while database table is having 500+ rows it goes out from while loop after 49th record

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * FROM mytable order by id", null);
Toast.makeText(this, "Row count---"+c.getCount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//giving 500 record
int ik= 0;
if (c != null ) {
while (c.moveToNext()) {
    ik++;
    Toast.makeText(this, " increment---"+ik, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//count upto only 49
}
}
```

please help

no error in try catch
But after 49th record it sends request to connect to wifi while i am not using any of wifi enable setting here

is there any alternative way to get all records.

thanks in advance

Comment: don't use toasts to log, use `Log`.

Comment: OR `System.out.println("Any string");`

Comment: i am testing it for android device

Comment: @NileshSolanki What does that have to do with what they said? Toast's are a bad way to debug stuff. Even worse for loops

Comment: Even if you are testing it for an Android device, the Log messages will appear in your LogCat in either Eclipse or Android Studio (assuming the app is running with the phone plugged in)

Comment: but what to do about "wifi" connect request after some of toast messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a thing, I guess:

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * FROM mytable order by id", null);
Toast.makeText(this, "Row count---"+c.getCount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//giving 500 record
int ik= 0;
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        ik++;
        Log.i("CursorCheck", " increment---"+ik);//should count until the last one
    } while(c.moveToNext())
}
```

Notice the `c.moveToFirst()`. Otherwise, a cursor can be at any inconvenient place. That way you ensure you get them from the beginning.

I also changed your check to use Logs, otherwise, having 500 Toasts might be exhasperating

Comment: The cursor returned by `rawQuery` is guaranteed to be before the first row.

Comment: Then all my life is a lie. No, actually, I expected `getCount` and other methods could mess with cursor positions. If it doesn't, I've no clue. Here comes an up arrow

Comment: In addition what was written by CL., this will actually skip the first row.

Comment: Did I mention that `rawQuery` never returns `null`? Anyway, the problem might be that Android does not want to display more than 50 toasts …

Comment: oh well, @CL, that could simply be the problem

Comment: @laalto, true, dammit, I'm too rusty with this. I added one of those old looking do whiles so this was somehow solved, but I'd better just delete the answer, I guess